# Indexes getting unordered when numbers are sorted in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Am trying to make a simple program in pandas which takes a list of random numbers from the user and stores it in **.csv format** and sorts those numbers and saves it again in the csv file.
But the problem here is that, the user's numbers are sorted but the **indexes** of the dataframe are being changed. How to rearrange them properly?

 **Input**

```
print("####### Sorting Numbers in CSV ####### \n")

import pandas as pd

n = int(input("How many random numbers would u like to give : "))
print("Give {} random numbers : ".format(n))
n_list = [] #Numbers list
for i in range(0,n):
    n_list.append(int(input()))
df = pd.DataFrame(n_list)


df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\adity\Desktop\Practice\practice.csv',header=True)
print("Before Sorting : ")
print(df)

sorted_n = df.sort_values(by=[0])
print("After Sorting : ")
print(sorted_n)
sorted_n.to_csv(r'C:\Users\adity\Desktop\Practice\practice.csv',header=True)
```

**Output**

```
How many random numbers would u like to give : 3                                                                                                                 
Give 3 random numbers :                                                                                                                                        
3                                                                                                                                                              
2                                                                                                                                                              
1                                                                                                                                                              
Before Sorting :                                                                                                                                               
   0                                                                                                                                                           
0  3                                                                                                                                                           
1  2                                                                                                                                                           
2  1                                                                                                                                                           
After Sorting :                                                                                                                                                
   0                                                                                                                                                           
2  1                                                                                                                                                           
1  2                                                                                                                                                           
0  3
```

Comment: By 'properly' do you mean in ascending numerical order?

Comment: Yes in numerical order

Comment: Ok... I'm not sure why you would want that, but, you can just set it with `sorted_n.index = range(sorted_df.shape[0])`

Comment: If you want to access rows by using the ordered position, you can still do that using `iloc` even with the out of sequence `index`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexes map to rows, so changing the order of the rows changes the order of the indexes.
If you want to generate a new index for the sorted dataframe, you need to use `ignore_index=True`:

```
sorted_n = df.sort_values(by=[0], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
In [791]: sorted_n = df.sort_values(by=[0]).reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)                                                                                                                             

In [792]: sorted_n                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[792]: 
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

Comment: It would be easier to do `df.index = range(len(df.index))`